# Can Gatsby/GraphQL leverage javascript files?

Tags: javascript, graphql, handlebars.js, gatsby

I'm porting over my site from a different site framework to Gatsby. I am currently importing my old site and sourcing the files using `gatsby-source-filesystem` however this only gives me information *about* the files versus the contents. I've ran into some transformers for the markdown files as part of my exploration, but I want to know if there's anyway to leverage my javascript (.js) and handlebars (.hbs) files to obtain the objects within them and possibly output them onto a page.

Comment: gatsby is react based ... you can use them in gatsby if you know how to use them in react

Comment: I'm interested in knowing if I can access the contents of .js files and .hbs files using GraphQL.

Comment: can you pass them by json? custom data source maybe? simpler ? ... probably you can get filename/path, evaluate, use result in render or similar, usual 3rd party usage in react